How to interpret geometries with color, stroke etc from EPS file using ghost script?
Given the EPS file how to extract geometry information with colors using GhostScript source code.The extracted geometries needs to be drawn after EPS is interpreted using c++ gdi.

You can't, easily, extract that kind of data. You either need to redefine all the operators you are interested in so that they dump the current relevant portions of the graphics state or you need to write a Ghostscript device which receives all the marking operations and again extracts the relevant portions of the graphics state. If you narrow the scope of the question it might be possible to write a workable answer but at the moment this is essentially an open-ended question.

@KenS Well that's what I figured. Is there any document I can refer to write a ghostscript device ? –
Niraj
Commented2 hours ago

There are no specific documents on writing a device. You can look at the online documentation (https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Develop.html) but the normal way is to start by taking an existing device and either gutting it to get a skeleton framework or modifying it if it is sufficiently close to what you want. You could try the PXL output devices as a starting point (ghostpdl/devices/vector/gdevpx.c)

The trace device might do what you want, but it isn't built in as standard so you'd need to modify the makefiles. Look at ghostpdl/devices/gdevtrac.c
